# how to connect to a postgresql database using libre office base?

Tags: postgresql, libreoffice-base

I think it surpringly difficult to find some clarity on how to connect to a postgresql db using libre office base...

Is it one of the name in the drop down menu? Or do i need to install a plugin ?

[image]

Comment: You need to use either the `JDBC` or `ODBC` selection, provided that you have the appropriate driver installed for either. It all spelled out in the documentation [Base](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/en-US/text/shared/explorer/database/dabawiz00.html?&DbPAR=BASE&System=UNIX).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I could see in some tutorial they have a postgresql option in the drop down menu, hence my asking

Comment: There is a 'native' `SDBC` driver for Postgres, but I would avoid it as it is beta at best. In fact you will probably find the `Base` experience not all that satisfying. I gave up on it some time ago.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver What would you recommend as a GUI for postgres ? I'm just starting with it and the more official pgadmin seems quite dreadful as well. Something similar to db browser for sqlite would be amazing.

Comment: I don't use a GUI for managing Postgres, I use the command line client `psql`. It is lightweight, complete and runs close to the server. In other words if you can't get something to work it is probably an error on your part not intervening layers in a stack. To be honest I have not fooled with `Base` in year or two, so it might be worth it to try it out and see if it meets your needs. For application front ends I use Web based solutions, in past Django and for my new projects Flask.

Answer (score 3):

Had to `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql`

https://www.uzerp.com/blog/2019/05/06/libreoffice_postgres/